# Signature calculation to access Amazon Bedock

Tags: node.js, signature, amazon-bedrock

I am trying to make a POST request to Amazon Bedrock without using SDKs in Nodejs/JS.  I managed to tweak the code given in here:  ([How to sign POST request with AWS Signature Version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244772/how-to-sign-post-request-with-aws-signature-version-4)) to access S3. But generating the Signature the same way did not work with Bedock. It says

```
      message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.'
```

Appreciate if someone can show a code snippet to talk directly to Amazon bedrock in NodeJS / JS without using amazon sdk s

-RR-

I tried tweaking the code given in here:      [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244772/how-to-sign-post-request-with-aws-signature-version-4)
}

Here is my NodeJS code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import crypto from 'crypto-js'
async function send() {
    //AWS credentials
    const access_key = "XXXXXXXXX"
    const secret_key = "XXXXXXXXX"
    const method = 'POST';
    const service = 'bedrock';
    const region = 'eu-central-1'; //'us-east-1' 
    const host = 'bedrock-runtime.' + region + '.amazonaws.com/model/anthropic.claude-v2:1/invoke';
    //const host = 'bedrock-runtime.' + region + '.amazonaws.com'
    const canonical_uri = '/'
    const base = "https://"
    const content_type = 'application/json';
    const amz_target = '';
    var request_parameters =''
    // Create a date for headers and the credential string
    const amz_date = getAmzDate(new Date().toISOString());
    const date_stamp = amz_date.split("T")[0]; 
    //request parameters are passed in the body of the request and the query string is blank.
    const canonical_querystring = ''
    var payload = {
        "prompt": "\n\Utterance: Hello how are you\n\nAssistant:",
        "max_tokens_to_sample": 300,
        "temperature": 0.5,
        "top_k": 250,
        "top_p": 1,
        "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31"
    };  
    //var payload = "{'prompt' : 'Hello how are you'}";
    var payload_hash = crypto.SHA256(payload)
    //Choose Signature headers. 
    const signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'
    //const signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date'
    //const signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'
    //const signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'
    //Create cannonocal_headers according to the signed_headers used above
    var canonical_headers = createCanonicalHeaders(signed_headers, host, payload_hash,amz_date)
    console.log('\ncanonical_headers:\n' + canonical_headers)
    //create canonical request
    const canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
    var canonical_request_hash = crypto.SHA256(canonical_request)
    const algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    const credential_scope = date_stamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
    const string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  canonical_request_hash  //.toString()
    console.log("\nstring_to_sign:\n",string_to_sign)
    // Create the signing key
    const signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, region, service)
    // Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
    var signature = sign(string_to_sign, signing_key);
    // Put the signature information in a header named Authorization.
    const authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
    console.log("\nauthorization_header:\n" + authorization_header)
    //request headers
    const headers = {
        'Authorization':authorization_header,
        'Content-Type':content_type,        
        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256':payload_hash, 
        'X-Amz-Date':amz_date
    }
    // ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
    var response = await axios({
        method: method,
        baseURL: base + host, 
        url: canonical_uri,
        data:JSON.stringify(payload), //request_parameters,
        headers: headers,
    });
    console.log(response)
}
//call the send() function
send()
//Function implementations
function sign(key, msg) {
    return crypto.HmacSHA256(msg,key)
    //return crypto.HmacSHA256(crypto.enc.Hex.parse(msg), key)
}
function getSignatureKey(key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key), date_stamp)
    var kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    var kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    var kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning
}
function createCanonicalHeaders(signed_headers, host, payload_hash,amz_date) {
    var canonical_headers =''
    if(signed_headers.includes('content-type')) {
        canonical_headers = canonical_headers  + 'content-type:application/json' + "\n"
    }   
    if(signed_headers.includes('host')) {
        canonical_headers = canonical_headers + 'host:' + host + "\n"
    }
    if(signed_headers.includes('x-amz-content-sha256')) {
        canonical_headers = canonical_headers +  'x-amz-content-sha256:' + payload_hash + "\n"
    }
    if(signed_headers.includes('x-amz-date')) {
        canonical_headers = canonical_headers + 'x-amz-date:' + amz_date + '\n' 
    }
    return canonical_headers
}       
// this function converts the generic JS ISO8601 date format to the specific format the AWS API wants
function getAmzDate(dateStr) {
    var chars = [":","-"];
    for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
        while (dateStr.indexOf(chars[i]) != -1) {
            dateStr = dateStr.replace(chars[i],"");
        }
    }
    dateStr = dateStr.split(".")[0] + "Z";
    return dateStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) or [aws4-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4-axios). Back in the day i tried to sign manually and didnt managed to do it